# Как выйти за границу view, чтобы произошло наложение на следующий элемент?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть список элементов(recycler view), у каждого элемента в конце есть выпадающий список , как сделать так чтобы выпадающий список выходил за границу элемента?)

Ну т.е в раскрытом состоянии накладывался на следующей элемент?

Comment: выпадающий список это spinner?

Comment: @TimurVI да или какая-нибудь кастомная view

Comment: А диалоговое окно (AlertDialog) сильно испортит внешний вид?

Comment: Очень сильно, да

Comment: опишите в чем именно проблема, спиннер и будет открываться за границы айтема, еще можно использовать PopupMenu с кнопкой раскрытия, если элементов в списке не много (напр. пункты удалить, редактировать и тд)

Comment: @pavlofff у меня сейчас кастомная вью на основе LinearLayout

Comment: Думаю, вы выбрали неверное UX решение. Посмотрите для инспирации раздел Scrolling вот здесь: https://material.io/components/cards/cards.html#behavior